# How to select a selectbox an option value with JS?

Tags: javascript

This may sound easy but I'm been having a heck of a time to get this to work. Somebody please help. My select box is like below. How do i select the value 3 from the list?

```
        if(!empty($listeDoc))
        {
            $iGroups = 0;
            while($iGroups < count($listeDoc))
            {
            ?>  
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="productSelect[<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->DOC_CLIENT_ID ?>]['product_id']" id="productSelectCreation_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->DOC_CLIENT_ID ?>" onchange="setValueToOne(this)"  ><?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->DOC_CLIENT_NOM; ?>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name="productSelect[<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->DOC_CLIENT_ID ?>]['quantity']" id="productQty_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->DOC_CLIENT_ID ?>" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" style="width:100%; height:25px; border : #62270c solid 1px;" tabindex="1">
                        <option value=""/></option>
                        <option value="1"<?php if ($qty == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1</option>
                        <option value="2"<?php if ($qty == 2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2</option>
                        <option value="3"<?php if ($qty == 3) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>
                        <option value="4"<?php if ($qty == 4) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>4</option>
                        <option value="5"<?php if ($qty == 5) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>5</option>
                    </select>
                <td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $iGroups++;
            }
        }
```

here's is what i tried:

function setValueToOne(value)
{ 
    checkbox = document.getElementById('productSelectCreation');

```
if (checkbox.checked == true)
{
    document.getElementById("productQtyCreation").value = 1;
}
else
    document.getElementById("productQtyCreation").value = '0';
```

}

Comment: Instead of setting the value to `0`, set it `3`..?

Comment: my mistake, it should be 3

Comment: OK, that's it, what is the problem then?

Comment: can you try 'onchange' on select https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: it's not working...when i check the checkbox, nothing happen in selectbox...it remain blank

Comment: same with onchange

Comment: is it because my option value is like this : <option value="3"<?php if ($qty == 3) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>

Comment: [There's nothing wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/mu5n2pvg/1/) in your code. Please check what actually is rendered to HTML, and make sure `setValueToOne` is a global function.

Comment: @Dave You're going to sink to an endless mire of the dynamic ids. Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mu5n2pvg/2/), it uses event delegation, a single event listener, and no ids at all. If you've more than the mentioned checkboxes in your form, just give these selects manipulating checkboxes a class, and recognize the correct checkbox by className instead of type in the click handler.

Comment: @Teemu Woah......Thanks i've learnt something new....genius. Thanks Teemu..it works

Comment: @Dave I'll take my hat off to you, if you got the idea integrated to your code in less than twenty minutes = ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change the select box selected option using vanilla javascript. You will need to loop the selectbox and compare values.

```
 document.getElementById('productSelectCreation').onclick = function() {
    var val;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('productSelectCreation');
    var sel = document.getElementById('productQtyCreation');
if (checkbox.checked)
{
    val = "3";
}
else
    val = "0";
}

      var opts = sel.options;
      for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
        if (opt.value == val) {
          sel.selectedIndex = j;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think its not working because the checkboxes and selectboxes are dynamic (in a loop), ive updated the code

Comment: @Dave On the client-side those elements are static. Please check what do you actually get from PHP, the code you've provided works as it is, unless you're not trying to run it in an ancient IE.

Comment: @Teemu just followed your instruction..in a list of 5 generated checkboxes and its associated combobox...when i click on the 3rd checkbox, the value 3 appear in selectbox 1, which is wrong....i tried Vikash above code ..im having the same issue. I think i should collect the checkbox id and select the value 3 from the selectbox with same id...what do u think?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking something like this.

```js
function setValueToOne(chkbox)
{ 
   if (chkbox.checked) {
      alert("checked");
      alert(chkbox.value);
      document.getElementById("productQtyCreation").value = chkbox.value;
    } else {
      
      alert("Unchecked");
      document.getElementById("productQtyCreation").value = 0
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="productSelect" id="productQtyCreation" class="form-control1">
    <option value=""/></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="productSelect" id="productSelectCreation" onClick="setValueToOne(this)" value="3" />Test
```

Comment: @Dave does this helpful?

Comment: thanks Vikash....Could you I've updated my code above, could you please just check it again.....thanks

Answer (score -2):

```js
function setValueToOne(checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked) {
        document.getElementById('productQtyCreation').value = 3
    }else{
        document.getElementById('productQtyCreation').value = 0
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="productQtyCreation">
    <option disabled selected value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="productSelect" id="productSelectCreation" onClick="setValueToOne(this)" value="3" />
```